# How do I make this function send an email once and change an entity to "checked"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

Hi I have this function that sends an email if an entity contains "126d". It currently runs on every change, causing it to send me an email every time there's an entity with "126d" and every time there's a change.

Obviously I only want to receive the email once, so my solution would be to have a "status" column, where when an entity contains "126d" and an email has been sent once, it would change the "status" in the same row to "checked". Unfortunately my attempts in making it work have failed so far. I appreciate any help, thanks!

```
function CheckMail() {
  var mailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List").getRange("A1:A500"); 
  var data = mailRange.getValues(); 
  var dataLength = data.length;
      for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++){
        if(data[i][0] == "126d" || data[i][0] == "126D") {
          var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List").getRange("B1:B500"); 
          var name = range.getValues();
          var emailAddress = "email@gmail.com"
          var subject = "New parcel from " + name[i][0];
          var message = "Row " + (i+1) + " www.spreadsheet.com";
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        }
      }
}
```

UPDATE:
I tried @James Ds solution, but oddly enough it still sends a new email despite setting the status to "checked".

```
function CheckMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List")
  var data = ss.getRange("A1:D500").getValues(); // Read all data in A1:D500

  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ // Loop through all data
    if(data[i][0] == "126d" || data[i][0] == "126D" && data[i][3] != "checked") { // Check that A[i] is 126d and D[i] is not checked ([3] means col 3)    
      var emailAddress = "email@gmail.com" 
      var subject = "New parcel from " + data[i][1]; // get the subject from col B
      var message = "Row " + (i+1) + " www.spreadsheet.com"; // Message with row number
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); // Send the mail
      ss.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue("checked") // Set the 3rd column (D) to checked if the mail was sent
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havn't attemptet to set the value "checked" anywhere?

This code should do what you need with some minor modifications to the range and columns

```
function CheckMail() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List")
 var data = ss.getRange("A1:D500").getValues(); // Read all data in A1:D500

 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ // Loop through all data
     if((data[i][0] == "126d" || data[i][0] == "126D") && data[i][2] != "checked") { // Check that A[i] is 126d and D[i] is not checked ([C] means col C)    
  var emailAddress = "mail@gmail.com" 
  var subject = "New parcel from " + data[i][1]; // get the subject from col B
  var message = "Row " + (i+1) + " www.spreadsheet.com"; // Message with row number
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); // Send the mail
  ss.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue("checked") // Set the 3rd column (D) to checked if the mail was sent
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing it with another loop outside of the for-loop, no idea why I was over-complicating it.

Comment: Weird. After sending an email it adds the "checked" status, but if the spreadsheet is updated afterwards it still sends a new email.

Comment: @Nest please edit your answer and paste your updated code. It's more that likely the condition in the if statement wasn't changed? data[i][4] != "checked" the 4 should be changed to the index of the column where the checked is

Comment: updated it now. I changed it to 3, tried using 4 too, but it's not working. I thought the problem might be that the "and" condition only applies to the "126D", so I removed the "126d" condition, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Nest please see the updated code.. Encapsulated the OR condition and changed the column index in the AND condition.

Comment: that did it! I guess I misunderstood how the "getRange(i + 1, 3)" part works.